# Lost coordinate file name in process all outputs altogether

Tags: nextflow

```
def barcodes = (1..2).collect { String.format("barcode%02d", it) }
params.orifq = barcodes.collect { "fastq_pass/$it/*.fastq.gz" }

Channel
.fromPath(params.orifq)
.map { it -> [it.name.split("_")[2], it] }
.groupTuple()
.set{orifq_ch}

process cat {
debug true

publishDir = [ path: "Run/orifq", mode: 'copy' ]

input:
tuple val(bc), path(fq)

output:
path("*.fastq.gz")

"""
cat ${fq} > ${bc}.fastq.gz
"""
}

process all_stats {
debug true

publishDir = [ path: "Run/stats", mode: 'copy' ]

input:
path ("*.fastq.gz")

output:
path ("all_stats.txt"), emit: all_stats

"""
seqkit stat *.fastq.gz > all_stats.txt
"""

}
workflow {
cat(orifq_ch)|collect|all_stats|view
{
```

In this code,  process cat generated barcode01.fastq.gz and barcode02.fastq.gz, then all outputs from the precess cat were processed altogether in all_stats.

however, the all_stats.txt result in the file column showed 1.fastq.gz instead of barcode01.fastq.gz and the number 1 seems to be the FIFO serial number not the barcode number.

How to fix the code so the barcode number is correctly assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nextflow will rewrite input file names when a named pattern is used to declare a collection of files. In this case, the named pattern provided is `"*.fastq.gz"`. Note that the `*` wildcard is used to control the names of staged files. Otherwise (from [multiple input files](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#multiple-input-files)):

> When the input has a fixed file name and a collection of files is
> received by the process, the file name will be appended with a
> numerical suffix representing its ordinal position in the list.

However, the rewriting of input file names is completely optional. Instead,  you can just use a regular variable to bind the collection of files. This can then be used accordingly in your process script, for example (untested):

```
params.reads = './fastq_pass/barcode{0[8-9],[1-5][0-9],6[0-4]}/*.fastq.gz'
params.outdir = './results'


process cat {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/orifq", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    tuple val(bc), path(fq)

    output:
    path "${bc}.fastq.gz"

    """
    cat ${fq} > "${bc}.fastq.gz"
    """
}

process all_stats {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/stats", mode: 'copy'

    input:
    path fastq_files

    output:
    path "all_stats.txt"

    """
    seqkit stat ${fastq_files} > all_stats.txt
    """
}
```

```
workflow {

    Channel.fromPath( params.reads )
        .map { it -> [it.name.split("_")[2], it] }
        .groupTuple()
        .set { orifq_ch }

    ...
}
```

The reads pattern above will match barcodes 08 to 64 inclusive. It requires breaking the range down into multiple patterns and uses curly braces for each part.

Comment: Thank you very much, Steve, it worked. The barcodes collection was created so I can change the barcode number range for analysis. I tried the code like this (params.bcrange = (1..2)
def barcodes = (params.bcrange).collect { String.format("barcode%02d", it) })
and use (nextflow run XXX.nf --bcrange 1..12) to run the code but it didn't work. Can you suggest a better way to achieve that? Thank you so much.

Comment: thank you for the info and the code, hopefully Nextflow would include the range syntax in the future.

Comment: @Hanjié Actually there is indeed a better way, please see my edit above thanks.

Comment: ok that does simplify the barcode range assigning process. Thanks for sharing.